# AngularJS - Multiple 'ui-sref' in single 'ui-sref-active'

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing, ui-sref

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Order -->
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="order" class="main_link">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Order
    </a>
    <a ui-sref="order/create"><span class="plus">+</span></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

I want to add `class="active"` on `<li>`.

Whenever click on `<a ui-sref="order/create"><span class="plus">+</span></a>` this, that time `class="active"` add on `<li>`.

**BUT**

click on 
`<a ui-sref="order" class="main_link"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Order</a>` that time `class="active"` not add on `<li>`.

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config([ '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/flow");
            $stateProvider.state("home", {
                url : '/home',
                templateUrl : 'home.html',
            }).state("contact", {
                url : '/contact',
                template : 'contact',
            });
        }]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <li class="top" ui-sref-active="heaader_active">
    <a ui-sref="home"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>&nbsp;Home</a>
        <a ui-sref="contact"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>&nbsp;contact</a>                            
    </li>
  <ui-view/>
</body>

</html>
```

> style.css

```
/* Put your css in here */

.heaader_active {
    background: red;
}
```

More Detail Check [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLyDLNFQsg3ZJHra8GJR?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The way the `ui-router` is currently implemented it is not possible to do that. You can't specify for which particular `ui-sref` the `ui-sref-active` will be activated. That being said, it should be easier to adjust your template to wrap those links in such a way that you can have one `ui-sref-active` per one `ui-sref`. At least easier than adjusting `ui-router` behaviour.